# Cartesian Product and Set Difference - General Result

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We know that $(X\times X)\setminus(A_1\times A_2) = (X\times (X\setminus A_2))\cup((X\setminus A_1)\times X)$ but is there are general result for
$$\left(\prod_{i\in I}X\right)\setminus\left(\prod_{i\in I}A_i\right)$$
where $I$ is an arbitrary index set? I guess not but what can we do about finite $I$? Does there exist a "close form" for an inductive argument?

Comment: Don't you mean to ask whether there is a general result for $\prod_{i\in I}X_i\setminus\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ where $X_i=X$ for all $i\in I$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry I mixed it up. I will edit.

Comment: I found a result (which I believe uses induction) for finite $I$:

$$\left(\prod_{i=1}^n X\right)\setminus\left(\prod_{i=1}^nA_i\right) = \bigcup_{j=1}^n\prod_{i=1}^n\Delta_{i,j}$$ where $\Delta_{i,j} = \begin{cases} X\setminus A_i& \text{if $i=j$}\\X &\text{else.}\end{cases}\\$

But I now need a counterexample for why it does not work for infinite $I$ (as I believe there is no similar result for inifnite $I$).